# MYSQL SELECT DISTINCT songid, time ORDER BY TIME

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

i have a currently listening box on the homepage of my music website, and i have a table like this:

```
id,userid,songid,time
```

now every time a user plays a song, the id of the song is inserted into the songid field and also the time. so sometimes i have duplicate songid (inserted by different users).

Now here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT songid,time FROM songs ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10
```

that gives me the last ten songs that were listened, however sometimes it returns duplicate data too! how can i fix this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, which time do you want to display if there are multiple records with the same song at different times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to aggregate over `songid`:

```
SELECT songid, MAX(time) AS most_recent_time
FROM songs
GROUP BY songid
ORDER BY most_recent_time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You should order by `most_recent_time` to get the right order.

Comment: is there any way to boost this query,  because this takes a lot of mysql memory for some reason

Answer (score 4):

If the time is the datetime the song was last played, you can group the gons with the last time each was played:

```
SELECT songid,MAX(time)
FROM songs
GROUP BY songid
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This won't work. Most probably, it will skip all songs played more than once. You cannot rely on the values of ungrouped and unaggregated fields in the `GROUP BY` queries.

Comment: @Quassnoi The results of ungrouped and unaggregated fields in grouped queries are indeed undefined. However, neither are conditional on the grouping and so are unaffected. The implication that multiple plays will result in lost records in incorrect. The grouping affects the confitional `MAX` which is used to identify the last play for each song which is then sorted and the most recent 10 selected (i.e. exactly what's required)

Comment: this query: `SELECT  songid, time, MAX(time) FROM (
        SELECT  1 AS songid, 1 AS time
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  1 AS songid, 2 AS time
        ) q
GROUP BY
        songid
HAVING  time = MAX(time)` returns nothing, while the same query with `1` and `2` swapped returns a result. In other words, its result depends on the physical order of the records in the table. The physical order of the songs played will most probably be chronological so that songs played first go first in the heap / clustered index, and the songs played twice or more will be skipped.

Comment: @Quassnoi That's because you have an additional column of `time` which is affected by the `GROUP BY` in the manner you highlighted in your previous comment (ungrouped, unaggregated). Adding the time column to allow the `HAVING` to work broke the query and is not an correct representation. Try: `SELECT songid, MAX(time) FROM ( SELECT 1 AS songid, 1 AS time UNION ALL SELECT 1 AS songid, 2 AS time ) q GROUP BY songid HAVING 2 = MAX(time)`

Comment: if you didn't notice, I just copied your query.

Comment: @Quassnoi Actually, I did notice that you added a column of `time` so it is not an exact copy of the query. However it has highlighted a mistake in that I didn't have the MAX applied to time in the column specification - corrected, thanks

Comment: remove `MAX(time)` from the `SELECT` list if you like. The query still won't return the record.

Comment: @Quassnoi Thanks for the feedback. The issue wasn't with the `GROUP BY`, it was with the `HAVING` clause which wasn't necessary in this case. Clearly I was over complicating it. For anyone reading this long winded dicussion, I would recommend the solution by Kerrek SB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763492/mysql-select-distinct-songid-time-order-by-time/6763534#6763534

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    songs s
WHERE   id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    songs si
        WHERE   si.songid = s.songid
        ORDER BY
                si.songid DESC, si.time DESC, si.id DESC
        LIMIT 1
        )
ORDER BY
        time DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Create the following indexes:

```
songs (songid, time, id)
songs (time, id)
```

for this to work fast.

Unlike the `GROUP BY songid` solutions, this does not require a full table scan or a full index loose scan on `songs`.